# Call dynamic methods using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have a DynamicObject-based class that implements an interface dynamically (via TryGet* and TryInvoke*). I want to call the methods that it implements using reflection. The problem is that it throws a TargetException (Object does not match target type).

Like I said, it's dynamic, so it forwards the calls via a series of connections as text to another program, which then calls the destination method using reflection. It is basically a proxy class. The method names are known at compile time (because of the interface), but are called externally.

```
typeof(ITelescope).GetMethod(Console.ReadLine()).Invoke(prox,null);
```

ITelescope is the interface, `prox` is the dynamic object.

Comment: Could you post some code demonstrating the issue please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can not invoke a dynamic method with reflection, you can invoke *TryGet.../TryInvoke...* methods of DynamicObject which in turn execute your dynamic method...

```
dynamic obj = new MyDyn();
Console.WriteLine(obj.Text);

string methodName = "YourDynamicMethod";                    

var p1 = new ParameterModifier(2);
p1[0] = false; p1[1] = true;

var args = new object[] { new MemberBinder(methodName, true), null };

var res = typeof(DynamicObject).InvokeMember(
    "TryGetMember",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
    null,
    obj,
    args,
    new ParameterModifier[] { p1 },
    null,
    null);

var result = args[1];
```

---

```
public class MyDyn : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = "#" + binder.Name + "#";
        return true;
    }
}

public class MemberBinder : GetMemberBinder
{
    public MemberBinder(string name, bool ignoreCase) : base(name, ignoreCase)
    {
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject FallbackGetMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what that's for either. Looks good to me, I'm upvoting it. Seems like the best solution when you don't want or can't add a 3rd party dependency such as Impromptu. There're are other target clients such as WinRT when such thing is not feasible.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, dynamically defined methods are not available via reflection.  Part of this is due to the fact that they are truly dynamic - you could have a dynamic object where ANY method was valid, so there is no way for reflection to work properly in that scenario.  (ie: what would `GetMethods()` return?)

If the object is a dynamic object, the best option is usually to just assign it to a `dynamic`, and use the dynamic binding to get your method call:

```
dynamic yourObj = prox;
yourObj.Unpark();
```

Comment: Did you meant "dynamically defined methods are NOT avaiable via reflection"?

Comment: This does not work because I do not know the method name at compile time. Sorry, I should have included that in my question, I thought it was self-evident. I guess my code bit was a bit misleading. I've edited it to reflect that.

Comment: Everything is working off of the interface. It should then just invoke it in the prox object but it acts like it is a Typed object instead of a dynamic object. The invoke method should go through the normal process of calling `TryInvokeMember`.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler If the object doesn't actually implement the interface (only dynamically provides the interface's members), then invoking via the interface won't work, since C# is statically typed at it's core, and doesn't directly support duck typing.  In this case, using a library like jbtule mentioned might be a simpler approach (as you need to get the proper runtime binder to call the member, which isn't simple)

Answer (score 3):

If your trying to do something a little more meta than just using the dynamic keyword, you might be interested in a framework I wrote ImpromptuInterface (apache licensed, can be found in [nuget](http://nuget.org)).

Since it looks like you have an interface that matches up with your dynamic object, you can use Impromptu to [wrap your dynamic object with an interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBasic?tm=6) impromptu will dynamically emit an object that statically has an interface and will forward calls from that interface to a dynamic object using the dlr.

```
ITelescope iprox = Impromptu.ActLike(prox);
prox.Unpark();
```

Or if you just want to call a method of a dynamic object by a string name, similar to reflection, it also has a bunch of [reflection like methods](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding), that dynamically invoke dlr calls. It is less efficient than the interface way, but more efficient than reflection.

```
Impromptu.InvokeMember(prox,"Unpark");
```